# Random forest via tensorflow 2.3 is it possible?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, random-forest

I would like to impl. a random forest regression via tensorflow 2.3 but I cannot find any example for that. is it possible to do the random forest regression via tensorflow 2.3?

The same problem with svm, svr :/

I cannot use sklearn, because I have to use golang in running system. Maybe I can do the random forest regression via `sklearn` but how can I read the model via tensorflow? I think it is not possible.

Comment: Hi Tensorflow does not include Random Forest. Could you explain why you can't use it?

Comment: ok, for the learning phase I can use e.g. tensorflow, sklearn with e.g. python. The goal is to load the model into tensorflow (tensorflow is required). Tensorflow is used because at the end the software is running under golang.

Comment: In that case you could use a tf.estimator.BoostedTreeRegressor()

Comment: Or you could use tensor_forest which is under tf.contrib

Comment: I think that will be your answer https://medium.com/@dineshmadhup_75545/comparison-of-tensorflow-and-random-forest-model-with-python-92a475f84faa

Comment: @yuRa tf.contrib doesn't exist anymore under version 2.3

Comment: That's unfortunate then try the BoostedTreeRegressor()

Comment: Use `TensorFlow Decision Forests`. Take a look at [Tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests). Thanks!